# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM when using nanoid

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, nanoid

I am working on a URL shortener using Express and Typescript, and I use nanoid to generate the url ids. It is giving me ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error, specifically:

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /server/node_modules/.pnpm/nanoid@4.0.2/node_modules/nanoid/index.js from /server/src/model/shortUrl.model.ts not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in /server/src/model/shortUrl.model.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

The problem is, I am strictly using ESM, so there is not any 'require' that I should delete.

```
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid'

const nanoid = customAlphabet('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 6)

export interface ShortURL extends Document {
    shortId: string
    destination: string
}

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    shortId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        default: () => nanoid(),
    },
    destination: { type: String, required: true },
})

const shortUrl = mongoose.model<ShortURL>('shortUrl', schema)
export default shortUrl
```

What might possibly be the problem?

Comment: Is this TypeScript? Or is it transpiled by something?  If so, you need to check that you're configured to generate ESM code not CommonJS code.